# Setting up public AP

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, vlan

I´ve been wanting to set up a public ap and figured I could use my trusty old WRT54GL with DD-WRT and buy another router (with VLAn support) as my main router. The actual sharing would have to be connected over my normal network so I need some way to split the traffic from my normal stuff so not everyone can access it.

```
Main router ====> switch ====> Public AP
                     ====> My computer
                     ====> My laptop
```

Is VLAN "safe enough" as a solution splitting the public wifi from my network?
Is this possible?
Are there any better solutions, keeping in mind new wiring is not really feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLAN is your best option, on my side what i have done is i have used Squid proxy (i use linux, but squid works on windows too) and rerouted all the public traffic through Squid, while all of the other (my own, and my laptops) traffic is routed normally outside Squid, keeping in mind that squid caches objects which is the best way to save my bandwidth and money, but only downside is the public AP will be accessible only when the computer is turned on. That doesn't matters allot, my laptop remains ON all the day long, so i don't care about this....

I might not be answering on the way you have asked but i think what i have experienced is this... So there might be other great options too, but what was good to me and some experts was this!

Ahsan